# how to properly install admob, not showing up on some test phones

Tags: android, admob, android-xml

I need a clear example as to how to properly install andmob  in my application, very puzzling, I was able to figure out what I presumed to be the toughest part which was compiling it against 3.2 and setting the minimum sdk to 7 which is the minimum sdk I would like to target.

however

what I am finding now is that I am able to get it to work on my galaxy note, yet on my lg optimus one and galaxy apollo which are android 2.1 and 2.2 respectively neither of those phones ran the ads, not really sure how this makes any sense, I also find the admob documentation to be very confusing and unclear, I interpret it as saying that the developer can use either purely xml or purely java code to do this, Ive used purely xml here is my code in my manifest for the ad

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

**edit: layout xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/title_color_dark" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saysomething"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saysomethinginfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tweetedittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
        android:lines="4"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/charactersremaining"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/characters"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/posttweetbutton"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:onClick="posttweetbuttonClicked"
            android:text="@string/postbuttonstext"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14f5be094d0328"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**edit 2 new version of layout, makes dialog activity take up entire screen but still doesnt show an ad**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/title_color_dark" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saysomething"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saysomethinginfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tweetedittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
        android:lines="4"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/charactersremaining"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/characters"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/posttweetbutton"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:onClick="posttweetbuttonClicked"
            android:text="@string/postbuttonstext"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a14f5be094d0328"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

**edit 3 uses all linear layouts without any margin on the sides yet still doesnt produce an ad**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/title_color_dark" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saysomething"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saysomethinginfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tweetedittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
        android:lines="4"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/charactersremaining"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/characters"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/posttweetbutton"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:onClick="posttweetbuttonClicked"
            android:text="@string/postbuttonstext"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a14f5be094d0328"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: looks good so far, can you post your xml code?

Comment: Also, if you could describe what you find confusing, we are open to suggestions on how to make the documentation clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have included the code for the layout :D

Comment: I should also point out that the documentation I saw at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals outlined 3 steps then went on to only annotate 2 of the steps and then dive directly into the java code, I found this confusing however I was able to get it to work on my galaxy note in purely xml so I figured I had done the right thing

Comment: There is a page that talks about the alternative way to [define an AdView in XML](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml).  However, it is only linked near the bottom of the fundamentals page, and not on the sidebar - meaning it is probably too hard to fine.  Thanks for the feedback; this is on the list of todos to improve the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The AdView is 320dp wide, which is the entire width of the screen of most phones in portrait mode.  The AdView is sitting inside the LinearLayout with `android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"` so it doesn't have enough width to be able to show the ad.

If you check your logs, there is probably a warning like:

`Not enough space to show ad! Wants: 480, 75, Has: 456, 75`

To solve this, you'll need to either remove the margins on your top level layout, or move the AdView outside of your top level LinearLayout.

Comment: moving the adview outside of my top level layout truncated everything in the view, then I tried making another linear layout to house the adview and this crashed the app entirely, I should also point out the activity is a dialog activity, not sure if this is contributing to the problem or not

Comment: You aren't trying to put the ad in the dialog, are you?  If not, I don't think the dialog is part of the problem.  Also, how did it truncate everything in the view?  I would try using a top level RelativeLayout and align the AdView to the bottom of the screen, and  your entire tweet LinearLayout on top of the AdView.

Comment: I tried this but Im not getting an ad to display I have edited my initial question above with what my new xml layout looks like with the relative layout as the base layout, it has however made the dialog activity take up the entire screen which could be a problem because now the ad is way outside the users field of view

Comment: I'm a little confused - can you confirm if you are trying to put an ad inside of the dialog?  If so, I think the dialog itself has some padding, and you'll still have the original issue (have you checked the logs to see if you got the "not enough space" warning?  Anyhow, instead of `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` on your main LinearLayout, try putting in `android:layout_above="@+id/adView`.  It tells your main LinearLayout that the AdView is present, and needs to give it space on the screen.

Comment: Ive tried one more thing, this way uses all linear layouts but ensures there is space on both sides to show the ad, however despite the dialog activity still showing up the way its intended to there is no ad displayed, I will also place this into the edits above

Comment: sorry for the delay In my response had to step out for a second, however I have seen the error its says it wants 480 by 75 and its only getting 418 by 402, Im going to try this without the theme.dialog and see what happens

Comment: Well in version 3 there is still not enough room, because the parent's parent still has an 8dp left and right margin.  And if you're only getting 418, the dialog itself probably consumes some horizontal space, in which case an ad can't be placed in the dialog in portrait (unless you're using a larger phone like the galaxy nexus).  The Galaxy note is a tablet, which explains why it has the sufficient space to show the ad.

Comment: Interesting I greatly appreciate your help with this I would of pulled my hair out otherwise lol

Comment: So It appears that this cant be done in the theme.dialog, so since this is the case I will redo my activity so that I can get this to work, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ive decided to attempt to build my own custom theme.dialog using the theme.translucent and a custom background, from the looks of it that should work, thanks for the help!